# Mittag Leffler Theorem and double poles

Tags: calculus

My question it is possible to expand a function using Mittag Leffler theorem that has  double o triple poles ? y seem that it is possible only when f has simple poles and different than zero
[image]

Comment: [Arbitrary poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler's_theorem). This is only dealing with a special case allowing a particularly simple expansion. In general one needs to take a larger part of the Taylor expansion of the principal parts to achieve convergence.

Comment: so for example @Daniel the function $$\frac{z}{(z+2)^2 (z-5)^3}$$  has a double poles at -.2 and  triple pole at 5 and admit an expansion  different than laurent  series around the -2 or 5?

Comment: If you have only finitely many poles, the result is immediate. If $f$ is your meromorphic function, and the principal part at $a_k$ is $p_k\bigl(\frac{1}{z-a_k}\bigr)$, where the $a_k,\,1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ are the different poles, then $$g(z)=f(z) - \sum_{k = 1}^n p_k\biggl(\frac{1}{z-a_k}\biggr)$$ has only removable singularities at the $a_k$, so you have the decomposition $$f(z) = g(z) + \sum_{k = 1}^n h_k\biggl(\frac{1}{z-a_k}\biggr).$$ It's only when there are infinitely many poles that a convergence issue arises and one needs to add some holomorphic functions to achieve convergence.